# Problema em python no sublime text

Tags: python-3.x, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Bom, pessoal, estou com um problema quando eu coloco meu código em python no sublime text para rodar.

O problema é o seguinte, o código não funciona, só compila e mais nada.

No caso, ele não está executando nenhuma linha (tentando executar via CTRL+B versão 3.0).

Sou novo nesse editor, então me desculpem por qualquer ignorância.

```
a = float(input("Digite um número: "))
b = float(input("Digite outro número: "))
print(a)
```

Ele somente mostra uma esta mensagem:

```
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: Bom, consegui executar, mais, tem um porém. Quando executo, digito o primeiro valor, ele não vai pra próxima linha, exemplo. "Digite um número: 5(enter)", aí ele não vai para a segunda/terceira parte, que é receber o outro valor e printar o primeiro valor na tela.

Comment: Resolveu o problema com a resposta?

Comment: @kappa, resolveu seguindo esses passos ou realizou alguma etapa diferente ?
se sim, descreva por favor aí para gente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução para o problema é criar um sistema de execução (*Build System*) alternativo, para fazer isso siga os seguintes passos:

**1.** Numa nova aba do Sublime cole o seguinte código:

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "C:/Python27/Python.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

**2.** Onde está `"C:/Python27/Python.exe"` substitua pelo diretório onde está o executável do Python no seu computador com as barras `/` e não `\`como é padrão do Windows.

**3.** Salve o arquivo com o nome `Python_cmd.sublime-build` na pasta onde está instalado o sublime dentro de: `Data\Packages\User`.

**4.** No Sublime clique em `Tools > Build System`  e selecione `Python_cmd`, quando utilizar o atalho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> abrirá a janela do CMD pra executar os comandos do Python.

Comment: Pra mim não funcionou.

Comment: @Kappa, Qual o sistema operacional que você está utilizando? Qual a versão do Sublime Text? É versão instalada ou portable? Seguiu todos os passos? Qual o diretório do Python? Qual o diretório do Sublime? Me diz pra eu te ajudar.

Comment: Amigo, consegui resolver, obrigado!

Comment: @Kappa, que bom! :)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia

1. Para resolver esse problema, com uma aba do sublime aberta aperte
   **ctrl + shift + p**

   Irá abrir uma aba, nela digite **Package Control** e procure a opção de
   instalar.

   Agora na mesma aba instale o **SublimeREPl**

   Feche o sublime.
2. Agora vá em **Tools->SublimeREPL->Python->Python Run Corrent File**

   Para se ter um comando semelhante ao ctrl + b para compilar vá em:

   preferences-> key bindings e cole a seguinte linha:

[

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
{
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}}
```

]

Sendo o comando **ctrl+alt+b** agora usado para compilar.
Espero ter ajudado!

Esse vídeo mostra o procedimento

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5-niid0m8A