# Como compilar códigos Python no Sublime Text 3 executando no sistema operacional Linux?

Tags: python, sublime-text

Estou editando a pergunta para explicar melhor qual era minha dúvida.

---

Sou usuário linux e estou iniciando projetos web em Python. Logo fiz uso do editor de texto, Sublime text 3, porém o mesmo possui um problema para executar códigos em Python, ficando paralisada ou somente compilando o primeiro trecho do código.

Acredito que esse problema tenha acontecido para muitos usuários, logo faço a pergunta:

### Como executar ou compilar o código Python no Sublime Text 3?

Mas a pergunta ainda estava confusa, pois **meu desejo era emular o código Python no console que existe dentro do Sublime**.

Entretanto não tive sucesso, até fazer pesquisas em site estrangeiros e realmente entender que isso é uma falha do editor que se apresenta de formas diferentes, seja no Windows, Linux ou macOS.

Comment: Você teria algum problema em compilar o código diretamente no terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algumas horas de procuras intensas, descobri uma e mais maneiras de resolver esse problema. Embora não fosse a solução que preferisse, mas resolveu o problema e adicionou novas funcionalidades. 
Segue o link do youtube:

"Sublime Text 3 para desenvolvedores python" [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFciV6Ew5r4)

"Configurando Terminal python no sublime text 3" [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZq2qjDBaQQ&feature=youtu.be)

Boa sorte para quem precisar!!!

Comment: Olha essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175788

Comment: Opa laercio, vlw cara mas acabei encontrando em fontes estrangeiras como resolver. Porém a solução é quase a mesma, a diferença que uso o pacote "anaconda" da continuum como interpretador python, ao invés do python do meu próprio linux.

Comment: Entendido, seu sistema é linux, o da pergunta é Windows! (Y)

Comment: Sugiro que leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links/47#47 para evitar pontuação negativa nas suas respostas.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa indicar a localização do seu Python para o Sublime Text 3, já que o Sublime Text é um editor e não possui força para compilar ou interpretar programas.

Vá no menu do Sublime Text e realize os seguintes passos:

**`Tools<Build System<New Build System`**

Abrirá um espaço de editação dentro do seu Sublime Text 3, lá entro cole o seguinte código:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/home/maquiavel/anaconda3/bin/python27", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Depois salve como o nome que desejar - esse nome aparecerá no seu `build system`.

Essa parte **`/home/maquiavel/anaconda3/bin/python3`** varia de usuário para usuário, caso você esteja usando Windows pode ser que seja `C:\\python27\\python.exe`

Ficando:

```
{
        "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "selector": "source.python"
    }
```

Portanto, localize o diretório do seu python e cole o caminho dentro do **cmd**